# Yarn, node manager and resource manager

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

In YARN, which is of the following daemons takes care of the container and the resource
utilization by the applications?

1. Node Manager
2. Job Tracker
3. Task tracker
4. Application Master
5. Resource manager

I am confused for this , containers are taken care by node manager and resource utilization by applications is done by resource managers.

So the answer would be 1, 5.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.
Please give the correct answer options.

Answer (score 3):

All resource utilization on  a particular node is taken care by Node Manager.  Resource manager looks at overall cluster resource, and application manager manages progress of application.

Comment: So it is Resource manager who takes care about containers and Node manager will see to the resource utilization. The anserw for the above is Node manager and Resource manager.

Comment: Yes exactly. Think of Node Manager as "Task Manager in windows" for Nodes and Resource Manager as "Task Manager" for cluster